# T-SQL Clear Errors

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to clean up a huge legacy T-SQL stored proc. We call it from BizTalk.  BizTalk has a feature to retry a send port (for example 3 times every 5 minutes) when it is in error.

For example, the stored proc detects missing data and does this:

```
   if @CompanyID is null        raiserror( '@CompanyID is missing', 18, 1 );
```

The "Begin Catch" logic handles certain errors, (i.e. logs them to error tables), and then does a "Return 0".  I believe the prior programmer thought this would keep BizTalk from calling it again.  But now I have a trace and I can prove that BizTalk is calling it x retries every y minutes apart (as defined by the BizTalk SendPort).

My current thought is that if @@Error and @@ErrorMessage are not null, BizTalk still thinks it is in error, and will retry.

Any thoughts on how to totally clear the errors?  I was hoping to do a small quick fix, no time for a major rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post basically answers my question (this is also a post by me to zoom into clarification relating to error handling inside a catch block):

[T-SQL is error handling totally turned off in a "BEGIN CATCH" block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245900/t-sql-is-error-handling-totally-turned-off-in-a-begin-catch-block)

Certain statements in a try catch do not blow up.  They can set the error and the code keeps on falling through.

In this specific case, the catch block had an Insert into a table, and one column had been expanded in the stored proc, but not in the error table.  We expanded the column in other tables probably 4 months ago, but we never caught this insidious hidden issue with the error handler until this week.

I think that the other StackOverflow post will eventually help answer the question as to why BizTalk see this as an error.  I would think "return 0" would do it.  But since we were getting the truncation problem, that error was being sent to BizTalk.

In the real world, we rarely hit this error code, and when we do, the the particular column that was causing the error was not too big.   This error arose when a QA person began a certain test scenario and was putting in some invalid flight numbers in conjunction with a particularly long value for the offending column.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be applicable but if you increase the error level this may fix the issue by causing a more serious error to be logged.  Generally 1 through 19 I believe are more informational related and after 20 is considered a fatal error and will log the error in the SQL Log as well.  This may force the program to stop even if a handler is still believing it to be open.  You may always test this and see if it suits your needs and change it back if not.  You may also try a more proper BEGIN END blocking too and a generic return not returning a value for the catchs like:

```
IF @CompanyID is NULL
  BEGIN
     Raiserror('@CompanyID is missing', 20, 1);
     return;
  END
```

More on error catching here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: Your code makes sense, but I think there are about 10 or more Raiserrors tatements, and they were trying to use a common handler to write the error to database table.  My research actually began because some errors were too big for column size in the table, and we were getting a misleading truncation error msg, instead of the underlying Raiserrror msg.  I don't have the hours allocated now to correct everything, need to patch it.

Comment: Oh, and one other point.  BizTalk is kind of stupid, and in your code, if he sees an error, he will try to retry the stored proc.  This is great for timeouts, deadlocks, and such, but for user errors based on bad-data, it is really bad to allow BizTalk to re-run the stored proc with the same bad data, as the results will obviously be the same.  Thus, need to handle error, and return as if the stored proc succeeded so BizTalk doesn't bother retries.

Comment: You should be able to hit 'CTRL + H' in SQL Management Studio (depending on version) and do a mass replace for 'missing, 18' to 'missing, 20' and just raise the error level status to force a higher number.  This in and of itself, may force the operation to stop.

Comment: I'm trying to be clear, but guess I'm not.  If I throw a higher level error, BizTalk will retry the stored proc.  BizTalk is configured to retry for example 3 times every 5 minutes.  This is great for deadlocks and timeouts.  But when there is a user data error I want to handle the error and return gracefully.  Will just a "return" to that?  New Info: I'm still seeing a truncation error in my BizTalk event log, and even though I'm tracing almost every line of code, I cannot see where the truncation is, so that's what I'm looking at now.

Comment: You should not be using raiserror if you wish to continue on.  return is the equivalent of breaking out in my experience with SQL implementation.  If you are doing the begin try, begin catch blocks you may just handle the issue you are presented with by ignoring it if it is not mission critical to stop the presses to handle it.  You can even do a begin catch print '@ID was blank' end catch and it will print out information but not handle it like an error.  You may wish this instead as it will then continue on.

Answer (score 0):

If the error handling is SQL-based then it sounds like you may want to replace your RAISERROR completely and instead log your error at that point and simply return.

Also,  @@Error will never be null.  It will return a "new" value with each statement that is executed.  If the previous statement is executed successfully, it will return 0, otherwise it will return the error number....which in your case would be 18.  If your logic is keying off of @@Error, then you need to make sure it is being checked (or saved into a variable) immediately after the statement in question executes.

More info below.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190193(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190193%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Like I said, complete re-write is not an option at this time.  (See comments to @djangojazz above). I am not relyon on @@Error, but I'm afraid maybe BizTalk is.  However there are many SQL statements in the catch, that succeed, as I read it that should reset it.