# T-SQL is error handling totally turned off in a "BEGIN CATCH" block?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, error-handling, try-catch

I just want to confirm what I'm seeing.  Below is a small proof of concept Stored Proc I wrote that illustrates an issue I was having in a much bigger one.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TestErrorHandling
    @Param1 varchar(1) = ''  
AS
BEGIN
/*
Unit test: 
   DECLARE @returnStatus nvarchar(15);
   Exec @returnStatus = TestErrorHandling 
   print @returnStatus    
*/ 

BEGIN TRY   
    print 'Start' 
    IF @Param1 = '' raiserror( '@Param1 is missing', 18, 1 );
    print 'Should not see this' 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    print error_message() 
    print error_state()
    print error_number()
    INSERT INTO [FlightOrderUploadFailedLog]
           (EvtTyp) 
           VALUES ('max size of EvtType is only varchar(15) so this should cause truncation') 
    print 'after insert '
    print error_message() 
    print error_state()
    print error_number()
    return  -- added in second version (after original post) 

END CATCH 

END
GO
```

Output:

Start

```
@Param1 is missing
1
50000
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Procedure TestErrorHandling, Line 30
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
after insert 
@Param1 is missing
1
50000
-8
```

The surprising thing to me is that the program doesn't blow up on the "string or binary data would be truncated".  In other words, the code after that still runs.  Also, the error_message is not changed by a SQL error inside the catch block.

So the question is - what is the best practice for handling unexpected errors in the "BEGIN CATCH" section?  Should I have another nested TRY/CATCH?

NOTE: This was my original question, but I thought to put this question there would get it off topic and confuse the issue. After this one gets answered, I'll go back and update that one: [T-SQL Clear Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227567/t-sql-clear-errors/20228468?noredirect=1#comment30169526_20228468)

Part 2 - added later:

```
   DECLARE @returnStatus nvarchar(15);
   Exec @returnStatus = TestErrorHandling 
   print @returnStatus
```

This returns a -8.  Where the heck does -8 come from?

I'm also experiementing with adding a "return" vs a "return 0".  When BizTalk calls the stored proc, I want him to think it completed successfully, so as not to do the 3 retries every 5 minutes.

Added: I think this is mostly the answer I'm looking for: 
[SQL try-catch statement not handling error (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286667/sql-try-catch-statement-not-handling-error-sql-server-2008?rq=1)

But it does not discuss the best practice question I asked in this question.

UPDATE: Here is program to demo Allan's response:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TestErrorHandling2
    @Param1 varchar(1) = ''  
AS
BEGIN
/*
Unit test: 
   DECLARE @returnStatus nvarchar(15);
   Exec @returnStatus = TestErrorHandling2 
   print @returnStatus

This is proof of concept on error handling.   
See question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245900/t-sql-is-error-handling-totally-turned-off-in-a-begin-catch-block    
Testing to see if Truncation error stops or not. 

*/ 

    print 'Start' 

    INSERT INTO [FlightOrderUploadFailedLog]
           (EvtTyp) 
           VALUES ('max size of EvtType is only varchar(15) so this should cause truncation') 
    print 'after insert #1' 
    print 'Message=' + IsNull(error_message(),'null') 
    print 'State=' + IsNull(convert(varchar(4),error_state()),'null') 
    print 'ErrorNumber=' + IsNull(convert(varchar(8),error_number()),'null') 


BEGIN TRY   
    print 'Start - Begin Try' 

    INSERT INTO [FlightOrderUploadFailedLog]
           (EvtTyp) 
           VALUES ('max size of EvtType is only varchar(15) so this should cause truncation') 
    print 'after insert #2 ' 
    print 'Message=' + IsNull(error_message(),'null') 
    print 'State=' + IsNull(convert(varchar(4),error_state()),'null') 
    print 'ErrorNumber=' + IsNull(convert(varchar(8),error_number()),'null') 


    print 'The End' 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    print 'Catch'
    print 'Message=' + error_message() 
    print 'State=' + convert(varchar(4),error_state()) 
    print 'ErrorNumber=' + convert(varchar(8),error_number()) 
    return   -- error has been theoretically handled by writing it to a database 

END CATCH 

END
GO
```

Result:

```
Start
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Procedure TestErrorHandling2, Line 21
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
after insert #1
Message=null
State=null
ErrorNumber=null
Start - Begin Try

(0 row(s) affected)
Catch
Message=String or binary data would be truncated.
State=4
ErrorNumber=8152
-6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let me try for what I can.

"Best practice" - I hate that phrase because 9 times out of 10 it's purely subjective because somebody somewhere read something.

So my subjective answer is that seeing as you can nest try/catch and put a [try/catch within the catch block](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) - then I'd consider it good error handling to put a try/catch within the catch - IF what you have can throw an error and is severe enough that you wish to handle it yourself.

So IMO - best practice is yes, nest try/catch for better error handling.

Secondly - the reason your "catch" doesn't blow up is that the truncating error is not a batch terminating error. It's error level isn't high enough, so subsequent statements will be executed.
Simply try it out with a print statement:

```
PRINT 'something'
--do your insert here
PRINT 'somethingelse'
```

Then you'll see you should get both print statements.
You can even suppress truncate errors if you wanted to by changing ANSI_WARNINGS to OFF. Not that I would recommend, but well ... :)

If you had a try/catch within your catch, that should catch your truncate error because the severity is enough to trigger catch.

Comment: True, I tested it and I'm shocked.  The Insert totally fails, yet the code keeps running?  However, if you put it in a Try/Catch, the Catch logic is triggered.

Comment: It comes down to the severity of the error. _while a RAISERROR run with a severity of 11 to 19 in a TRY block transfers control to the associated CATCH block. Specify a severity of 10 or lower to use RAISERROR to return a message from a TRY block without invoking the CATCH block._ (msdn's raiseerror article)

Comment: I added my proof of concept for your example in UPDATE of original question.  I still don't understand where the -6 return code is coming from. If a c# program called the stored proc, would it know about the truncation issue.  Obviously SSMS shows us.  Or is this one of the optional returned messages that a lot of people never check in C#?  I'm actually calling from BizTalk SendPort, so I have that extra layer that I'm dealing with, trying to avoid the built-in retries with bad user data.

Comment: The -6 is due to the error in the query. A negative number as a return value is due to an error. Unfortunately - I can't off the top of my head remember a resource which specifies the error code numbers.

Comment: I updated original Q again, the first sample returns -8, the second one -6.  I'll keep hunting, just curious.  In my real world program, I'll probably do a "return 0" to clear this status.

Comment: Better to return the negative number, and in your return code and log it for further treatment and return 'false' or what ever back up :)
Otherwise you'll risk hiding errors.